# writing an algorithm using algorithm2e with the Comjnl.cls file of The Computer Journal?

Tags: algorithms

How to write an algorithm in Latex using the [Comjnl.cls](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-the-computer-journal-comjnl/xwtyhjrpbtvp) file of The Computer Journal?

The [`comjnl.cls`](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-the-computer-journal-comjnl/xwtyhjrpbtvp) defines algorithm environment such(line 347):

```
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
```

This clashes with `algorithm2e` environment. Minimal (not) Working Example:

```
\documentclass{comjnl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Write here the result }
 initialization
 \While{While condition}{
  instructions
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. The most popular packages for algorithms are `algorithm2e` and `algorithmic` (see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/algorithms). Have you tried any of those with that class? Was there a problem? Could you recreate the problem in a Minimal Working Example (MWE) and show us? Right now your question requires a bit more focus :)

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: I am using the algorithmm2e and write the command
  \ begin {algorithm}
...
\ end {algorithm}
"latex error command algorithm already defined. or name end ... illegal see p.192 of the manual" appears when compiling.

If you delete the command % \ newtheorem {algorithm} {Algorithm} in the comjnl.cls file, and error will not occur. So is there any other way? Because doing so will fail to transfer the source file to the journal

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question to make it clearer. This way we are more likely to get an answer from the community

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `algorithm` environment before loading `algorithm2e`:

```
\documentclass{comjnl}

\makeatletter
\let\algorithm\@undefined
\let\endalgorithm\@undefined
\makeatother

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Write here the result }
 initialization
 \While{While condition}{
  instructions
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks DG'!
Your guide helped me fix the error.
tex.stackexchange.com/ is number 1

Comment: @VyHuynh - If this answer solved your problem, then please accept it, so the question can be colsed. See: [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)